# Why does this ng-maxlength set my valid inputs as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add maxlength validation to my form fields, but when I add it in, it says that any length is invalid and always sets my $scope variables to 'undefined'.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenr4/41L26apv/

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.data = {
        'person1': {
            'firstname': "Steve",
            'lastname': "Rogers",
            'maxlength': 5
        },
        'person2': {
            'firstname': "Bob",
            'lastname': "Ross",
            'maxlength': 10
        }
    };

    $scope.pkeys = ['person1', 'person2'];

    $scope.log = function() {
        console.log($scope.data);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!<br>
  Sir, {{data.person1.firstname}} {{data.person1.lastname}}!<br>
  and, {{data.person2.firstname}} {{data.person2.lastname}}!<br>

  <div ng-repeat="key in pkeys track by $index">
    {{key}}<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data[key].firstname" ng-maxlength="data[key].maxlength"><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data[key].lastname" ng-maxlength="data[key].maxlength"><br>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="log()">
    Log the data
  </button>
</div>
```

Can someone help me fix this or at least explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this => ng-maxlength="{{..}}"

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!<br>
  Sir, {{data.person1.firstname}} {{data.person1.lastname}}!<br>
  and, {{data.person2.firstname}} {{data.person2.lastname}}!<br>

  <div ng-repeat="key in pkeys track by $index">
    {{key}}<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data[key].firstname" ng-maxlength="{{data[key].maxlength}}"><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data[key].lastname" ng-maxlength="{{data[key].maxlength}}"><br>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="log()">
    Log the data
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me, just tried it out in the fiddle and it was perfect!!
http://jsfiddle.net/stevenr4/41L26apv/1/